# simple quote issue for automate ansible ad-hoc command

Tags: shell, ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

I try to make shell script to automate some ansible ad-hoc command.

e.g.

```
/usr/bin/ansible app -m shell -a 'echo $HOME'
```

I write a simple script to automate this kind of tasks :

```
 #!/bin/bash
 set -x 
 ANS_BIN="/usr/bin/ansible"
 pattern="app"
 remote='echo $HOME'
 $ANS_BIN $pattern -m shell -a $remote
```

When I execute this, whatever I tried, simple quote are always misinterpreted.

```
./ans2.sh
+ ANS_BIN=/usr/bin/ansible
+ pattern=app
+ remote='echo $HOME'
+ /usr/bin/ansible app -m shell -a echo '$HOME' Usage: ansible <host-pattern> [options]
```

I know there is a lot of questions about simple/double quote escaping, but I just don't get it ! Impossible to get this working. How should I do escape this ?

Answer (score 2):

Try quoting the variable in the Ansible call like so:

```
$ANS_BIN $pattern -m shell -a "$remote"
```

Comment: Thx, but it doesn't work, with double quote, variable is expend, which i don't want in my case. I need that "$HOME" is expand on remote host, not when I launch ansible command.

Comment: This answer is right. The variable will not be expanded on your side, only on the remote side.